# How can I avoid repeating the type definition of a class and the properties passed to its constructor?

Tags: typescript

I am converting a JavaScript codebase to TypeScript. My JS class looks like this:

```js
export class Token {
  constructor(obj) {
    Object.assign(this, obj)
  }

  // additional methods
}
```

So the caller could pass all the initializing props, which worked but depended on the caller to do everything right.

Converting this to Typescript and making the constructor strict, I've come up with this:

```js
interface TokenProps {
  index: number
  length: number
  op: string
  phrase: string
  quotes: 0 | 1 | 2
  wild: '' | '*'
}

export class Token {
  index: number
  length: number
  op: string
  phrase: string
  quotes: 0 | 1 | 2
  wild: '' | '*'

  constructor(obj: TokenProps) {
    this.index = obj.index
    this.length = obj.length
    this.op = obj.op
    this.phrase = obj.phrase
    this.quotes = obj.quotes
    this.wild = obj.wild
  }

  // additional methods
}
```

but it's very repetitive. I understand that a class can't extend an interface, but I don't know how to avoid the repetition between the properties of the class and the object that should be passed to the constructor. How can I make this DRY?

---

This is the best I've been able to do so far. It feels wrong, mainly because of the bangs, but it does avoid the repetition:

```js
class TokenBase {
  index!: number
  length!: number
  op!: string
  phrase!: string
  quotes!: 0 | 1 | 2
  wild!: '' | '*'
}

type TokenProps = {[k in keyof TokenBase]: TokenBase[k]}

export class Token extends TokenBase {
  constructor(obj: TokenProps) {
    super()
    Object.assign(this, obj)
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually reuse the interface anywhere? Seems like this could just be a single definition with parameter properties on the constructor.

Comment: The class has a couple more static methods that can accept either an instance or the interface. But I'm also not sure I completely understand what you're proposing.

Comment: [Parameter properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties). Also: _"I understand that a class can't extend an interface"_ is true, only a _value_ can be extended, but it can [_implement_](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#implements-clauses) one.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers, but (1) as I understand it, parameter properties are positional, which hardly applies or helps here, (2) `implements` does not reduce the repetition. I'm grateful for your engagement, but I'm not sure this is answering my question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I believe OP is asking why [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDWEQAUroAOAzsgN4BQyyoAJhAB4BcyIArgLYBG0VyANjgDmYABYt23XtSItiYKKCF9CoqHGIQ5CpXwCObdJGIsADMgA+yAIyXkAJj4B3YP1osA5B7seAVB4oAXwpGQnQoMGQEfg1SDGwQGg5CQQ4cMDisHHwiUkpqBHQQeSg2BDBwgAp0LgArFnjsghIASnI+agB5OohygDpY4CEQSrFgYgAaZBralr5gwKA) doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: Thank you @tao. I may not have asked my question in the best way. You're right, I'm trying to understand how to do essentially what you posted, but in a way that works.

Comment: Afaik, [this is how you do it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDWEQAUroAOAzsgN4BQyyoAJhAB4BcyIArgLYBG0VyANjgDmYABYt23XtSItiYKKCF9CoqHGIQ5CpXwCObdJGIsADMgA+yAIyXkAJj4B3YP1osA5B7seAVB4oAXwpGQnQoMGQEfg1SDGwQGg5CQQ4cMDisHHwiUkpqOkYAQglOHig+QRARURLWMulkIjr5RWqVNQ0IFp126gMjCGI68ytbK0dqFzc6rx9-Cj4EdBBWtgQwcIAKdC4AKxZ47IISAEpyPmoAeX2IDYA6WOAhEC2xYGIAGib9075gwJAA). It does feel wrong to have to specify each of them again. Let's hope a TS guru shows us how to do it less repetitive and less error prone.

Comment: @tao I updated my question with my best attempt so far, starting from the example you provided.

Comment: That's pretty neat. Do you need more than that? Or you simply want to know if there's a better way? (e.g: avoiding the bangs!?) I do have a curiosity, though, why do you call `super()`? You haven't defined a constructor on `TokenObjProps`.

Comment: This isn't bad, but it would be nice to know if there's a better way (e.g. avoid bangs). Must call `super()` because we're extending a class, and TS complains otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255167/discussion-between-tao-and-aron-griffis).

Comment: There's nothing built into the language so if you use this sort of thing often you might want to make a helper `AssignCtor` factory as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mA261W). See the linked question and its answer for more information.